# How to use XML or JSON as a datasource in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

I would like to use a JSON or XML file to store my data in an ASP.NET core application.
Reason for this is that there is not a lot of data, and there is not a lot of changes in the data. The advantages would be improved speed of the application and that I do not need a database for the application (Saves money).

So the idea I would have is to serialize the data to an XML or JSON. When the application starts, this data should be loaded into memory.
On changes the file should be updated.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this, or is this a way of working that should be discouraged?

Comment: Improved speed?  Well if you're really after speed you would bypass serialization and reflection technologies and go for flat files.  But honestly, don't.  Sadly your question is too broad. [ask]

Answer (score 5):

No matter what data storage technology you decide to use, I would recommend you to abstract the data access behind some interface so that your application is not bound to a specific implementation. This would allow you to more easily switch to some other storage technology if you decide to in the future.

So if you want to use an in-memory datastore, then why not:

```
public interface IDataStore
{
    IQueryable<MyModel> Get();

    void Add(MyModel model);

    ...
}
```

which can be implemented like this:

```
public JsonDatastore : IDataStore
{
    private readonly string dataFile;
    private readonly IList<MyModel> data;

    public Datastore(string dataFile)
    {
        this.dataFile = dataFile;
        this.data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyModel>>(File.ReadAllText(dataFile));
    }

    public IQueryable<MyModel> Get()
    {
        return this.data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public void Add(MyModel model)
    {
        // If you want a lock free implementation you may consider
        // an algorithm which will only notify some underlying thread
        // that a change has been made to the underlying structure and
        // it will take care of saving those changes to the file system
        // This way it is guaranteed that only one thread is writing
        // to the file while the changes can be made in memory quite fast
        // (using a ConcurrentBag<T> instead of a list for example)

        lock (this)
        {
            // Make sure that only one thread is updating the file
            this.data.Add(model);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.data);
            File.WriteAllText(this.dataFile, json);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the last important bit is to ensure that you configure the `Datastore` lifetime instance in your Dependency Injection container as **singleton**.